# Cannot find the bug in QuickSort implementation?

Tags: c#, algorithm, templates, quicksort

I am applying the QuickSort algorithm from book introduction to Algorithm i wrote the  code,but the output is not sorted correctly

Following is the algorithm

```
Quicksort(A, p, r)
{ 
  if (p < r)
  {
    q = Partition(A, p, r)
    Quicksort(A, p, q-1)
    Quicksort(A, q+1, r)
  }
}
```

---

```
Partition(A, p, r)
{
  pivot = A[r]
  i = p - 1
  for j = p to r – 1
  {
    do if A[j] <= pivot
      then
      {
        i = i + 1
        exchange A[i]  A[j]
      }
  }
  exchange A[i+1]  A[r] 
  return i+1
}
```

---

and here is my code

```
 class Threads<T>
 {
    static bool IsLessThan(T x, T y) 
    {
        if (((IComparable)(x)).CompareTo(y)<=0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public int Partition(T[] myarray, int low, int high)
    {

        T x = myarray[high];
        T y;
        int i = low - 1;
        int j;
        for (j = low; j < high - 1; j++)
        {
            //**************Added Text after edit,I forgot to put this  

          if (IsLessThan(myarray[j], x))
            {
                i++;
                y = myarray[i];
                myarray[i] = myarray[j];
                myarray[j] = y;                

            }
        }

        y = myarray[i+1];
        myarray[i+1] = myarray[high];
        myarray[high] = y;
        return i + 1;
    }

    public void QuickSort(T[] myarray, int low, int high)
    {
        if (low < high)
        {
         // int q = Partition(myarray,highh, low);
            int q = Partition(myarray,low, high);
            QuickSort(myarray, low, q - 1);
            QuickSort(myarray, q + 1, high );
        }
    }
}
```

Following code shows, how the quicksort method is used

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int[] myarray ={9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2};
        textBox1.Text = "";
        Threads<int> t1 = new Threads<int>();
        t1.QuickSort(myarray, 0, myarray.Length-1);
        for(int i=0;i<myarray.Length;i++)
        textBox1.Text=textBox1.Text+" , "+myarray[i];
    }
```

I get the Following output when i execute the program

**8 , 7 , 6 , 5 , 4 , 3 , 9 , 2**

### Answer

1. value of i must be one less than j and low at start in the Partition function
2. I forgot to Swap myarray[i+1] and myarray[high] outside the loops in Partition Function.

Now the code is working accurately fine for strings ,int ,char etc

Comment: Start with small array and debug your code. Or use existing solutions - there is no point writing your own if you are not willing to debug/test it yourself.

Comment: You have an array small enough that you can work out by hand every single step. Do so. Then watch your algorithm in the debugger. The moment the program does something wrong, there's your bug.

Comment: take a look at this one http://snipd.net/quicksort-in-c

Comment: why is this downvoted? Seemed like an honest question.

Comment: @syclee (not my downvotes) because there is no question - answer to "how to fix this quicksort implementation" is "use built in one like `OrderBy`", but OP is probably looking for some other help... but not stated what exactly needed.

Comment: ok, fair enough. Maybe it's good to leave a constructive feedback when downvoting (not directed at you of course)

Comment: @FAST - I've changed your question into "how to debug", if you have better question to put into it - feel free to rollback and edit.

Comment: **(1)** `j < high - 1` should be `j < high`. **(2)** You forgot `exchange(i,j)` in the loop. **(3)** `Partition(myarray, high, low)` should be `Partition(myarray, low, high)`. **(4)** Outside the loop, both `myarray[i]` should be `myarray[i+1]`. Then it works.

Comment: @Dukeling ,Your comment is an answer , and value of i must be less than j at the start in Partition

Answer (score 1):

First this part looked plain wrong, but even after changing the sort doesn't work

```
    int q = Partition(myarray, high, low);
```

Low and high should be changed

```
    int q = Partition(myarray, low, high);
```

I think this question is less about an algorithm, and more about the methods of debugging one.  So I used a Quicksort algorithm I found online and tried to implement it in C#. I had problems of my own, but debugged it fairly quickly.  The code below has some useful techniques to help with debugging.  (The algorithm came from http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Quicksort.)

Here are my general comments when comparing your code:

1. It was confusing having an array of ints to test with when dealing with integer indices as well, so I changed my array to strings.
2. I used a lot of Console.WriteLine so I could trace the steps the algorithm was taking.  That's what quickly helped me find that low/high issue.
3. I didn't not use a variable named *i* as anything but a for loop index.  That's just confusing as all heck to use it as anything else -- don't do that!
4. Since every QuickSort algortithm had multiple swaps I created a Swap function.  Even if you only do it once in your code, it clutters up the purpose of the Partition method to have such a trival pattern in there.  To put this another way, why did it make sense for you to make IsLessThan a method but not Swap?
5. Speaking about IsLessThan, technically you actually wrote a method for IsLessThanOrEqual.  Don't name things incorrectly, because if somebody uses that and assumes it is just for Less Then, they'll have a hard time when they have unpredictable results.  IsLSE would be understandable by most.
6. Your for loop is the only place you use the variable *j* so why declare it outside of the for statement?  Just adds an extra line and variable in a scope you don't need it.

Here's my QuickSort.  It appears to work:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string[] myarray = { "g", "b", "e", "f", "a", "d", "c"};

        QuickSort<string> t1 = new QuickSort<string>();
        t1.Sort(myarray, 0, myarray.Length - 1);
    }
}

public class QuickSort<T>
{
    static int Compare (T x, T y)
    {
        return ((IComparable)(x)).CompareTo(y);
    }

    private void Swap(T[] myarray, int i, int j)
    {
        // swapping indices just for writeline purposes
        if (i > j)
        {
            int t = i;
            i = j;
            j = t;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Swap: {0}:{1} with {2}:{3}",
            i, myarray[i], j, myarray[j]);

        T temp = myarray[i];
        myarray[i] = myarray[j];
        myarray[j] = temp;


        Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}", String.Join(",", myarray));
    }

    private int Partition(T[] myarray, int low, int high, int pivotIndex)
    {
        T pivotVal = myarray[pivotIndex];
        Swap(myarray, pivotIndex, high);
        int currentLow = low;

        while (low <= high) {
            while (Compare(myarray[low], pivotVal) < 0) {
                low++;
            }
            while (Compare(myarray[high], pivotVal) > 0) {
                high--;
            }
            if (low <= high) {
                Swap(myarray, low, high);
                low++;
                high--;
            }
        }

        return low;
    }

    public void Sort(T[] myarray, int low, int high)
    {
        if (low < high)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(("Start: {0}", String.Join(",", myarray));
            int pivotIndex = (low + high) / 2;
            Console.WriteLine("QuickSort: P: {0}, L: {1}, H: {2}", 
                pivotIndex, low, high);
            pivotIndex = Partition(myarray, low, high, pivotIndex);
            Sort(myarray, low, pivotIndex - 1);
            Sort(myarray, pivotIndex + 1, high);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 - useful debugging tips targeting particular algorithm. I've changed question so it somewhat more inline with SO guidelines and matches your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

public int Partition(T []myarray, int low, int high)
    {

```
    T x = myarray[high];
    int i=low;
    int j=high;

    while(i< j)
    {
       while(i<j&& IsLessThan(myarray[i], x))
           i++;
           myarray[j]=myarray[i];
       while(i<j&& IsLessThan(x,myarray[j]))
           j--;
           myarray[i]=myarray[j];

    }

        myarray[i] = myarray[high];

        return i ;
}
```

Comment: Your code makes duplicate values of some elements during sorting

Comment: it it does not equally partition the Array

Answer (score 1):

Try some changes and debug your code
I tried following

```
private static int Partition(int[] input, int left, int right) 
{     
int pivot = input[right];     
int temp;       
int i = left;     
for (int j = left; j < right; j++)     
{         
if (input[j] <= pivot)
{             
temp = input[j];
input[j] = input[i];
input[i] = temp;
i++;
}
}
input[right] = input[i];
input[i] = pivot;
return i;
}
```

if Pivot element is middle element

```
private static List<int> QuickSort(List<int> a, int left, int right)
{
int i = left;
int j = right;
double pivotValue = ((left + right) / 2);
int x = a[Convert.ToInt32(pivotValue)];
int w = 0;
while (i <= j)
{
    while (a[i] < x)
    {
        i++;
    }
    while (x < a[j])
    {
        j--;
    }
    if (i <= j)
    {
        w = a[i];
        a[i++] = a[j];
        a[j--] = w;
    }
}
if (left < j)
{
    QuickSort(a, left, j);
}
if (i < right)
{
    QuickSort(a, i, right);
}
return a;
}
```